# Is there any way to get all meta and standard columns for any WordPress object after searching based on meta key and value

Tags: custom-field, database, query

I have a scenario where I have a meta key and value and a WordPress object name, I want to search based on the meta key and value and retrieve all details stored in db, for example if this is for a user I want the data from *wp_users* and *wp_usermeta*, same goes for other objects that have a object and an objectmeta table.

For search I have been using the query classes *WP_Query*, *WP_User_Query*, and other related classes. I get the standard attributes from there, but to get the meta attributes I still need to call another function.

I am wondering if there exists a method where this can be done, as a last resort I can always go and write inner join queries on my own.

Any leads on this are appreciated.

Comment: Basic question, I know, but since you didn't specifically mention this I thought it best to ask....have you tried adding global $post to your query?  That lets you access all metadata associated with any specific post. 

Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables

A good discussion here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170358/when-to-use-global-post-and-other-global-variables

Comment: Thanks for the lead Trisha but I believe I wont be able to use the global variable $post I am not working with a specific post, I have a meta and its value, I wanted to see if there is a way to get the post and all its data by querying based on the meta field and value, and also this is not limited to posts, I am exploring for a similar mechanism for all other WordPress objects like User, Terms, etc.
Feel free to correct me if I have got anything wrong here.

Comment: Gotcha, in that case what you use is the WP_Meta_Query, you can read how to use WP_Meta_Query here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/