# Rewrite rules and query for virtual page

Tags: rewrite-rules, query-variable

My question comes from [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/173808/31545). I have never really touched on rewrite rules as frankly, they still do not make sense to me

### What I have

I have successfully build the following link

```
http://localhost/wordpress/custom-archive/
```

which should, by default, lead to a 404 page, as `custom-archive` does not exist. It is the same as visiting

```
http://localhost/wordpress/category/
```

That part works fine.

Now, what happens, this link comes and only shows on a single post when the single post has categories and tag attached to it. If the post has categories and/or tags, I add the relevant category ID's and tag ID's to the link through custom `query_vars`. The link then looks like this

```
http://localhost/wordpress/custom-archive/?cq=21&tq=18,19,20,144
```

### OTHER IMPORTANT INFO

- I can, using `template_include` that whenever either one of the two `query_vars` exist, use a custom template. This works
- By having a custom query on that specific template, display the correct posts

### MY PROBLEM

Although I get posts with a custom query ( which I also want to eliminate ), the main query 404's. This can be seen in my breadcrumbs and in the browser tab which displays "Page not found"

### WHAT I'VE TRIED

I have used `pre_get_posts` to get the values from my custom `query_vars` to alter the main query, but this does not work as Wordpress tries to read the page as post or single page

I have also tried rewrite rules, which also does not help my cause. The problem here is, I really can't get the correct combination. I know I have to somehow tell Wordpress that this page is a custom archive and not a post or a page and then use the values from my custom `query_vars` in a `tax_query` to get posts that belongs to the categories **AND** tags given in the custom `query_vars`

Any suggestions to the correct rewrite rules to achieve this?

### EDIT

I know I have to somehow rewrite

```
http://localhost/wordpress/custom-archive/?cq=XXX&tq=XXX
```

to something where Wordpress can understand that this an custom archive page (or vitual page) for the post type `post`, and the posts should that should be displayed on the page should match posts that are in the categories given by `cq` **AND** has tags which is given by `tq`.

This is a basic idea of what works in my custom template with a custom query

```
$args = [
    'post_type'    => 'post',
    'tax_query'    => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'terms'    => get_query_var( 'cq' ),
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'terms'    => get_query_var( 'tq' ),
        ],
    ],
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I need to translate this to work for the main query. Simply adding the above to `pre_get_posts` does not work, the page simply 404's, so somehow the URL needs to be rewritten for this to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a posts archive by just setting `post_type=post` in your rewrite rule:

```
function custom_archive_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'custom-archive/?',
        'index.php?post_type=post',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_archive_rule' );
```

WordPress will identify this as `is_home`, so you'll have to target it in `pre_get_posts` by the existence of your extra query variables.

```
function custom_arcive_tax( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home()
        && $query->is_main_query()
        && isset( $_GET['cq'] ) ) {
            $tax_query = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'terms' => $_GET['cq'],
                )
            );
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_arcive_tax' );
```