# (get_post_ancestors == 2) is returning true on 1 as well?

Tags: hierarchical, count, children

I am trying to use this code:

```
<?php if(count(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)) == 2 ) : ?>
        <script>...</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

to add a script to a page **but only if** the page is a **grandchild page** (3rd level down, when it has 2 ancestors):

**Desired Result (with code above):**

- Parent Page

  - Child Page

    - Grandchild Page ***(show script here only)***

But the script is showing on child pages as well as grandchild pages. Why would that be?

**Actual Result (with code above):**

- Parent Page

  - Child Page ***(script is showing here)***

    - Grandchild Page ***(script is showing here)***

---

**EDIT**: this is my query code on the children pages (with a different ID for post_parent, depending on the child page):

```
<?php $args = array('post_parent' => 21); 
   $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
?> 
... 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Works when I try it. What is the output of `var_dump(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));`?

Comment: I get this on the parent page: `array(0) { }` and this on the child and grandchild pages `array(2) { [0]=> int(21) [1]=> int(10) }`

Comment: does `var_dump($post->ID)` yield the correct ID on both pages?

Comment: Then you child page is not a true child page. You will need to verify your hierarchy, because clearly, from the `var_dump()` your child page is actually a grandchild. If your hierarchy is correct, your code in which you are running the code above has issues,  (*using `query_posts` which will break code, a bad filter or a bad query*) in which case it will be best to add all relevant code.

Comment: @PieterGoosen - I'm not quite sure how to decipher the `var_dump` output. I don't think I'm doing anything strange with my code and the pages are setup as children and grandchildren in the pages menu of the Wordpress admin.

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar - hmmm...no, actually. The children pages return the wrong ID's with `var_dump($post->ID)`. What could/does that mean?

Comment: Something in your page is changing your code, as I said, you, a plugin or your theme is using `query_posts` (*which you should never ever use*), or you have a bad query on the page or a bad filter. What the `var_dump()` means is that something is changing your child page to grandchild page. Disable all plugins and check if the issue persists, if it does, test your code on a bundled theme. Also, set debug to true and check for obvious debugging errors. Your issue is just way to localized t answer or to help you. Follow what I have said, you should find the bug somewhere

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar - for example, on a child page with ID of `21` (I know it is 21 because of the link in the pages menu in Wordpress admin) the `var_dump($post->ID)` returns `int(125)` ???

Comment: @PieterGoosen - okay, doing that now. Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is changing your results from `get_ancestors()` or something is changing your query which "changes" your child pages to grandchild pages when queried on the page. It also seems from comments that the post ID's does not stay constant on the page.

What immediately catches my eye from your updated code is that your custom query is not resetted after you are done. You have to remember, `the_post()` sets the `$post` global to the current post being looped over in the loop, and once the loop is done, `$post` will hold the last post object of the loop.

You can add `var_dump( $post );` before and after your current code and you will see that the value of `$post` differs. That is why you must **always** reset custom queries after you are done. Simply add `wp_reset_postdata();` directly after `endwhile` just before `endif`. Doing a `var_dump( $post );` now before and after the loop should render the same value.

`$post` is a global variable that is changed by many things, and bad code (*like the code in your question*) can change the `$post` global, which in turn returns wrong info, which in turn have you on a wild goose chase to find out why. A more reliable method is to use `get_queried_object()` to return the current page object. For an explanation, please feel free to check [my question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/167706/31545) and the answer accepted answer from @gmazzap. Note, however this being reliable, `query_posts` breaks the main query object which holds the queried object.

I also note that you hardcode ID's, do not do that. Every post/page have a `post_parent` property. If a post type is non-hierarchical, like posts, the `post_parent` value will always be `0` because non-hierarchical post types don't have any hierarchy. Hierarchical post types like pages will either have `0` as `post_parent` if it is a top level page or have a numeric value if it is child/grandchild page, the value in `post_parent` will represent the ID of the page's direct parent.

- To correctly get the page id of a page being viewed, use `get_queried_object()->ID` or `get_queried_object_id()` instead of `$post->ID`.
- To get the immediate post parent ID of the current page being viewed, use `get_queried_object()->post_parent`
- To get the top level parent, use `end( get_ancestors( get_queried_object()->ID, 'page' ) )`. Remember, the top level parent will be the last ID in the array of ID's returned by `get_ancestors`, the first ID will be the direct parent.

To rewrite your code, use something like this to get direct children of the page being viewed:

```
$page_object = get_queried_object();
// Check if page is top level or not and set $args accordingly
if ( $page_object->post_parent == 0 ) { // Top level page
    $parent_ID = (int) $page_object->ID;
} else { // Page is a child/grandchild page
    $parent_ID = (int) $page_object->post_parent;
}

// Setup query args
$args = [
    'post_parent' => $parent_ID,
    'post_type'   => 'page'
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();

        // Run your code to display posts

    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // EXTEMELY IMPORTANT!!!!!!!
}
```

To conclude, to determine the current hierarchy of a page, do the following

```
$current_page = get_queried_object();
if ( $current_page->post_parent == 0 ) {
    echo 'This is a parent';
} else {
    $hierarchy = get_ancestors( $current_page->ID, 'page' );
    $count = count( $hierarchy );
    $child = ( $count == 1 ) ? 'child' : 'grandchild';
    echo 'This is a ' . $child . ' page';
}
```

Comment: `wp_reset_postdata()` was the culprit. I don't have an `endif` in my loop, but adding `wp_reset_postdata();` after `endwhile` returns the same ID now before and after the loop. Your code rewrite at the bottom of your answer is gonna take me some time to understand but for now my original code is working as I was expecting it to. I didn't expect a simple "echo this script if on a grandchild page" setup to take 2 days to figure out...gotta love coding, eh. Thank you very much for your help. Something little/edit (for future readers): `wp_reset_postdat()` is missing an "a" at the end.

Comment: I'm glad you got this solved. Thanks for the note on the missing `a`. One do miss some minor syntax when posting from small screen devices :-). The last block of code is just for testing basically, so you do not have to break your head on this right now. ;-). Enjoy and good luck on your project

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the $post->ID right at the wp hook:

```
add_action('wp','your_awesome_function');


function your_awesome_function()
{
     global $post;
     if( count(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)) == 2 )
          add_action('wp_footer','your_grandchild_script');
}

function your_grandchild_script()
{
     ob_start();
     ?>
          <script>...</script>
     <?php
     echo ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I appreciate it. A lack of `wp_reset_postdata()` at the end of my loop was the culprit, as noted in the accepted answer & comment.