# Display a thumbnail outside of the loop for a page

Tags: post-thumbnails

Is it correct that to dispaly a post thumbnail image outide of the loop you need to associate the post ID from the page?

Like this:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be correct yes. Just a tip here, `$post` is not reliable due to the fact that many use (*knowing or unknowingly*) `$post` as local variable which breaks the `$post` global. A simple `$post = get_post( 'some custom id' )` which you might think is innocent, actually sets the `$post` object to the post you are querying, so `$post` no longer holds the page you are viewing's object.

Custom queries which uses `the_post()` or `setup_postdata( $post )` also changes the value of the `$post` global, so you would get the incorrect post object if you or someone else forgot to reset the postdata (*the extremely important `wp_reset_postdata() which so many forgets*) after the custom query.

I always tell people to test this practice, do `var_dump( $post );` before a custom query, then create a complete custom query but "forget" to add `wp_reset_postdata()` and do a `var_dump( $post );` after the query. The result will clearly show that `$post` is changed to the last post in the custom query.

To have more reliable results, use `get_queried_object()` to get the full queried object on true pages, single pages and archive pages. On true pages and single pages, the post object will be returned, on archives like category and tag pages, the term object will be returned, etc.

If you only need the ID, you can always use `get_queried_object_id()`.

You can use:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id() );
```

outside the loop to get the thumbnail of the page being viewed.

Just one final note, although this is very very reliable, it does break with the use of `query_posts` as `query_posts` resets/breaks the main query object. That is why one should never ever use `query_posts`

### EXTRA RESOURCE

- [Should we trust the post globals?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167706/should-we-trust-the-post-globals)

Comment: Did not know about 

echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id() );

So that was god to know about and will read up on it more.