# Meta description - template code to get category description

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

Below is the code I wrote for header.php so that the description for a product category can be obtained and used for the `<meta>` description tag when viewing such a "page" on the site.

Is there a more "WordPress way" to do this such as a function I should be using instead of referencing the `description` property of the object returned by `get_queried_obj()`?  I originally wanted to use `term_description()` but that adds `<p>` tags so I didn't end up going that route (I know I could strip them with a built-in function but that doesn't seem like good practice).

The `elseif` block below is the key piece of code:

```
<?php
if (is_single() || is_page()) {
    $description = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'description', true);
} elseif (is_tax()) {
    //Product categories
    $obj_temp = get_queried_object();
    $description = $obj_temp->description;
} else {
    $description = get_bloginfo('description');
} 
if (trim($description) !== '') {
    ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description); ?>" />
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more "WordPress way" to do this...

I don't really know what you mean by a more WordPress way, but in general, the way you are getting the term description is a more reliable way in doing it. This way, you do not need to access the `$post` global which so many people use. Just for interest sake, please see [my post here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/167706/31545) on why to avoid the `$post` global

I would however get the queried object from the `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object()` which is even more reliable than `get_queried_object()`, and then pass that through [`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) to apply the term filters to the term

```
} elseif ( is_tax() ) {
    //Product categories
    $obj_temp    = get_term( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );
    $description = $obj_temp->description;
}
```

Another probable way is to get the term slug and taxonomy from the URL and then get the complete term object to get the description

```
} elseif ( is_tax() ) {
    //Product categories
    $obj_temp    = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') );
    $description = $obj_temp->description;
}
```

### EDIT - from comments

> How is `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object()` more reliable than `get_queried_object()`

We actually had a discussion about this which lead to [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/220624/31545) to the following question

- [$GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] vs global $wp_query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/220619/31545)

You should really read that as I explained everything in detail there. Just a quick proof of concept to add to that answer in this context, in any template, preferably a page or taxonomy template, run the following and see the results

```
var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );
var_dump( get_queried_object() );

query_posts( 's=crap' );


var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );
var_dump( get_queried_object() );
```

> Also, what's an undesirable situation that might result if the term filters didn't get applied to the term

Term data is not sanitized, specially when used directly from a super global, so it may contain injected malicious code or hacked URL's to some hardcore porn site which you do not want. Applying the term filters sanitizes the data according to term field to make it save to use.

Sanitizing, validating and escaping data should be a habit, and not a debatable extra. Hackers love non-sanitized and non-validated data, they can inject any malicious code into your site and through that gain access to your site. The best advice I can ever tell you forever is, ALWAYS SANITIZE, VALIDATE AND ESCAPE all data according to data type, regardless of where it comes from (*even if it comes from you yourself*) or what it will be used for. This way, you make it extremely hard for hackers to hack your site

Comment: How is `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object()` more reliable than `get_queried_object()` (I'm not saying it isn't, just wondering since I don't know the answer)?  Also, what's an undesirable situation that might result if the term filters didn't get applied to the term? Thanks

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It was a bit to much for comments ;-)