# $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] vs global $wp_query

Tags: wp-query

What is the difference between `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']` and `global $wp_query`?

Why prefer one over the other?

Comment: I would say `global $wp_query` just to answer your question in one line!

Comment: What is the difference?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have missed one, `$GLOBALS['wp_query']`. For all purposes, `$GLOBALS['wp_query'] === $wp_query`. `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` is however better for readability and should be used instead of `$wp_query`, BUT, that remains personal preference

Now, in a perfect world where unicorns rule the world, `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] === $GLOBALS['wp_query'] === $wp_query`. By default, this should be true. If we look at where these globals are set (*[`wp-settings.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.3.2/wp-settings.php#L407-L422)*), you will see the main query object is stored in `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']` and `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` is just a duplicate copy of `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']`

```
/**
 * WordPress Query object
 * @global WP_Query $wp_the_query
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
$GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] = new WP_Query();
/**
 * Holds the reference to @see $wp_the_query
 * Use this global for WordPress queries
 * @global WP_Query $wp_query
 * @since 1.5.0
 */
$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
```

The reason for doing it this way, is because WordPress saw the arrival of [`query_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) in version 1.5.

```
function query_posts($query) {
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = new WP_Query();
    return $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query($query);
}
```

As you can see, `query_posts` sets the main query object to the current custom query beign run. This breaks the integrity of the main query object, which gives you incorrect data, so anything that relies on the main query object is broken due to wrong data.

A way to counter this was to create another global to store the main query object, `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']` which was introduced in version 2.0.0. This new global hold the main query object and `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` just a copy. Through `wp_reset_query()`, we could now reset `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` back to the original main query object to restore its integrity.

But this is not a perfect world, and `query_posts` are the devil himself. Although thousands of warnings, people still use `query_posts`. Apart from breaking the main query, it reruns the main query, making it much slower as a normal custom query with `WP_Query`. Many people also do not reset the `query_posts` query with `wp_reset_query()` when done, which makes `query_posts` even more evil.

Because we cannot do anything about that, and cannot stop plugins and themes from using `query_posts` and we can never know if a `query_posts` query was reset with `wp_reset_query()`, we need a more reliable copy of the main query object which we know will give us 99.99999% reliable, correct data. That is where `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']` is useful as no WordPress related code can change it's value (*except through the filters and actions inside `WP_Query` itself*).

Quick proof, run the following

```
var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] );
var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_query'] );

query_posts( 's=crap' );


var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] );
var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_query'] );
```

and check the results. `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']` did not change, and `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` has. So which is more reliable?

Final note, `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']` is **NOT** a replacement for `wp_reset_query()`. `wp_reset_query()` should **always** be used with `query_posts`, and `query_posts` should **never** be used.

### TO CONCLUDE

If you need reliable code which will almost always never fail, use `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']`, if you trust and believe plugins and theme code and believe no one uses `query_posts` or is using it correctly, use `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` or `$wp_query`

### IMPORTANT EDIT

Being answering questions on this site now for a couple of years, I saw many users using `$wp_query` as a local variable, which in turn also breaks the main query object. This further increases the vulnerabilty of the `$wp_query`.

As example, some people to this

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

which is in essence the exactly the same as what `query_posts` are doing

Comment: [query_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) changes `global $wp_query`.  `global $wp_the_query` holds the reference to **[the main query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_main_query/)**

Comment: My comment wasn't intended as a correction, so my apologies if it did.  I was merely summarizing (TL;DR if you will) while pointing out what I believe is one of the most significant aspects of `$wp_the_query` as it pertains to the `WP_Query::is_main_query()` method, which was not mentioned :D

Comment: @EvanMattson Apologies, I misunderstood your first comment ;-). Yes, `is_main_query()`, which is a wrapper for `WP_Query::is_main_query()` which checks the current query object against the main query object saved in `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']`. This is quite important when you run `pre_get_posts` actions and just want to target the main query ;-)

Comment: Pretty well done answer! @EvanMattson That should have been an [edit].

Comment: Can you include mention of `is_main_query` function in the *IMPORTANT EDIT section? I was using `pre_get_posts` today and found it utterly useful to use that function since I was looking at `$wp_query`.

Comment: Just pointing out that `global $name` and `$GLOBALS['name']` are synonymous. They always point to the same object. So, there are only two objects: `global $wp_query` and `global $wp_the_query`

Answer (score 3):

The global keyword imports the variable into the local scope, while $GLOBALS just grants you access to the variable.

To elaborate, if you use `global $wp_the_query;`
you can use `$wp_the_query` inside the local scope without using the word global again. So basically `global $wp_the_query` can be compared to `$wp_the_query = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']`

**EDIT**

I misread wp_query for wp_the_query so my answer isn't a complete answer to the question but still provides general information about the difference between `global $variable` and `$GLOBALS['variable']`

Comment: Please, file an [edit] as this really is not an answer to the original question. Just FYI `$GLOBALS['foo']` allows _overriding_ or unsetting the variable as well. So it's a _bit_ more than what you describe here.

Answer (score 3):

Basically one is copy of the other.