# Pagination 404 on my index.php

Tags: php, pagination

I'm trying for days how fix pagination on index of my wordpress site.
Pagination work great on category and other archive but doesn't work on my index

clicking on the page numbers have a 404.
I found that the links point to **domain.com?paged=4.**
**Replacing  ?paged=4 with ?page=4 the pagination work!**

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                    <?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args   =  array(
                    'post_type' => array(of_get_options( 'url_movie', 'movie') ),
                    'showposts' => get_option('posts_per_page '),
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'paged' => $paged

                ); 
            query_posts($args);
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


<li class="item">
                <a class="poster" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php if(show_info('name', $post->ID ) == "N/A"){echo show_info('title', $post->ID ); }else{echo show_info('name', $post->ID );} ?>">
                <img src="<?php image_show("poster_path", $post->ID, "w185"); ?>" alt="<?php if(show_info('name', $post->ID ) == "N/A"){echo show_info('title', $post->ID ); }else{echo show_info('name', $post->ID );} ?>" />              
                </a>
                <div class="info">
                <h3 class="name"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php if(show_info('name', $post->ID ) == "N/A"){echo show_info('title', $post->ID ); }else{echo show_info('name', $post->ID );} ?>"><?php if(show_info('name', $post->ID ) == "N/A"){echo show_info('title', $post->ID ); }else{echo show_info('name', $post->ID );} ?></a></h3>
                <span class="genero"><?php $category = get_the_category($post->ID); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></span>
                </div> 
            </li>  
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>

          <?php  if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
    wp_paginate();
}
else {
    pagenavi();
} ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What have you tried, what worked, what didn't work? Please update your post with (a lot) more information.

Comment: clicking on the page numbers have a 404. I found that the links point to domain.com?paged=4. Replacing ?paged=4 with ?page=4 the pagination work!

Comment: There are more than enough resources on site as to why to **NEVER EVER** use `query_posts`. You should be using `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query to your needs, which there are also enough resources on site

Comment: `pagenavi()` and `wp_paginate()` both functions are not from WordPress, query var is wrong, `query_posts` is a bad practice.

Comment: You can find out about [Pagination on the WordPress CodeX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) and also you can see every `function` that WordPress has to offer by visiting [Function Reference on the WordPress CodeX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference)

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why you should not run [`query_posts()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/385) are perfectly outlined in this answer. Long story short: You overwrite the default query (that happens by WP core) and replace everything that was valid for this request with data that only matches for your secondary query.

- The function [`get_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) relies on the global `$wp_query` that gets reset by your `query_posts()` call. This is what happens inside this function:

  ```
  $GLOBALS['wp_query']->get( $var, $default );
  ```
- The [`wp_reset_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/) function, does re-sync `$wp_query` with `$wp_the_query`. This is what happens in its core:

  ```
  $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
  ```

  More details about the *how* can found in this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/220624/385).

**Answer:** Basically you are nuking all the globals that WordPress relies on. And as plugins need to rely on WP core, you nuke that one as well.