# Targeting Parent Category Pages

Tags: categories, taxonomy

I wish to create different template pages for all Parent Categories and Subcategories. I was hoping to do it using the hierarchy (eg. something like `category-parent.php` and `category-sub.php`), but looking at the flow diagram I found, I don't think there's an option:

[image]

I could manually add a `category-$slug.php` for the parent categories (as these shouldn't be changing) and then just use `category.php` for everything else (ie. the subcategories), but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using custom template and [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter.
`category-parent.php` and `category-sub.php` both are not required. One can be `category.php` for parent categories and for child categories, you can use `custom-category-child.php` as `category-sub.php` is reserved for default hierarchy.

- First create a template file in theme `custom-category-child.php`
- Then add this code to your theme `functions.php`

**Update**: As Pieter suggested we can use `category_template` instead of `template_include` to save few lines. Additionally we should return current template when our custom template file is missing!

**Read inline comments**

```
add_filter('category_template', 'custom_cat_templates');
/**
 * Create custom template for child categroies
 * @param type $template
 * @return type
 */
function custom_cat_templates($template) {
    $category = get_category(get_queried_object_id()); //Get the ID for current queried category
    if ( $category->category_parent > 0 ) { //Check if it child category
        $sub_category_template = locate_template('custom-category-child.php'); //return our custom template
        $template = !empty($sub_category_template) ? $sub_category_template : $template; //return default template if custom templaet missing
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: You can just use the `category_template` filter. Also, your code will break if  `locate_template('custom-category-child.php')` is empty

Comment: Yes, exactly, you should make provision for when `custom-category-child.php` is missing.

Comment: Updated code. Thank you I was not aware of this filter `"{$type}_template"` ;)

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way if you code the same in the `category.php` file.
Check if the category is a parent category. And if so, then display parent code. Otherwise show the child code. This way you do not need to create multiple files for each category.

```
$category = get_term(get_queried_object());

if ( $category->category_parent > 0 ) {
    // Is subcategory
} else {
    // Is parent category
}
```

Comment: This is not a very reliable method

Comment: @PieterGoosen Could you elaborate a little further? I just about to use this  method.

Comment: The code has some serious flaws and will not never work unfortunately

Comment: Also, it relies on post categories, say a post has many categories, and the queried category is not the first category... Unfortunately, this is totally incorrect

Comment: @PieterGoosen I fixed the code, but my fixes were rejected the community. Very odd. I'm trying again.

Comment: From what I can see, this is the reason: *This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.*

Comment: @PieterGoosen Ha! This is what the OP wants to do, they just went about it the wrong way. It completely preserves the intent and isn't worth a new answer by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to take the [scenic route posted by @Sumit (*which IMHO is a better solution*)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/222363/31545) and need do do things inside the category template, you can do the following

- Get the queried object (*currently viewed category*). We will use `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object()` which is 99.9999% reliable opposed to `get_queried_object()` or even the suggested `get_the_category()`. You can read my interesting answer to the subject [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/220624/31545)
- Use [`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) to validate the term object (*you can also use `get_category()`, but is short, `get_category()` is just a wrapper for `get_term()`*)
- From there, we can get the category parent and do what we need to do

We can try the following:

```
// Get the current category object
$category_object = get_term( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );

// Run our logic according to the value of $parent
if ( 0 === $category_object->parent ) {
    // Category is top level
} else {
    // Category is a descendant
}
```

Comment: You've since fixed it (added `->parent`). You were previously testing to see if an object was `=== 0`. Your fix is why I deleted my comment and removed my downvote.

Comment: AH! I see, saw that when I reviewed my code and fixed it immediately