# Load custom posts with same tag as page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, categories, tags

I'm using this plugin to add tags for a page:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-tags-and-categories-for-pages/

And I've added tags support for the custom post:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'label'  => 'Doing',
      'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt')
    );
    register_post_type( 'doing', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

In every page with an specific tag I want to display related custom posts that have the same tag as the page, is this possible to do? How can I get to load on the page the tag related custom posts?

I've tried with this code but is not showing any related post:

```
  <?php
      $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
      if ($tags) {
          echo 'Related Posts';
          $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
          $args=array(
              'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
              'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
              'posts_per_page'=>5,
              'caller_get_posts'=>1
          );
          $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
          if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
              while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

               <?php
               endwhile;
          }
          wp_reset_query();
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: Where did you put that related posts code ?

Comment: @Sumit I've put that code in the page template, not in the custom posts template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify a post type in your `WP_Query` arguments when you need to query any other post type accept the build in post type `post`.

By default, `post_type` is set to `post`, so when no specific post type is set manually by the user, `WP_Query` will query posts from the post type `post`

Additionally, `caller_get_posts` have been deprecated for a very very long time now. If you had debug turned on, you would have recieved a deprecation notice about this. The correct arguments to use is `ignore_sticky_posts`.

I would also not use the `$post` global as it is unreliable, for reliability, rather use `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object()`. You can read up on this subject in [my answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/220624/31545)

[`get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/) is also faster than `wp_get_post_tags()` as the latter requires an extra db call.

One last note, `wp_reset_query()` is used with `query_posts`, the correct function to use with `WP_Query` is `wp_reset_postdata()`

In essence, you can try the following

```
$post_id = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object_id();
$tags = get_the_tags( $post_id );
if (    $tags
     && !is_wp_error( $tags ) 
) {
    $args = [
        'post__not_in' => [$post_id],
        'post_type'    => 'doing',
        'tag__in'      => [$tags[0]->term_id],
        // Rest of your args
    ];
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Your loop

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Pieter, I'm using this code on my page template. The page has the same `tag` as a `doing` custom post. But the output when I put `echo the_title();` in the `// Your loop` part is another type of custom post which doesn't even has the `'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')` support :/

Comment: @wpuser This is the crystal clear answer. Not sure why you are having troubles! When you `echo the_title();` did you setup the postdata using `the_post()` ?

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks Pieter for the great explanation, again :) I'll award the bounty as soon as its possible to do it.

Answer (score 2):

My first port of call is to call `global $post;` - as that sets you up to use `$post->ID` ... if you are using it then the next step is to display each part separately e.g.

```
print_r($tags);

echo $first_tag;
```

see what's displayed in each part, this will help diagnose where the issue is, as without seeing your code working, we can't say why it's not working.

Comment: The output I get is `array()` :/ I put it like you suggested: `<?php
        global $post;
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
        print_r($tags);
        echo $first_tag;
    ?>`

Comment: if you get array then that means it's empty, so you need to work out why it's empty before you can move onto the next step.