# difference between $wp_the_query and $wp_query? & getting the values properly

Tags: wp-query

i have seen `$wp_query` and `$wp_the_query` in many plugins and themes. for me these two are just same thing with no difference. i am not looking to either use or get the values from $GLOBALS.

what is the actual difference between these two objects and when to use them? 
What is the proper action /filter hook for getting and reading values from `$wp_query` and `$wp_the_query`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should read in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220619/globalswp-the-query-vs-global-wp-query/220624) it explains it in depth.

in short,

- `$wp_query` is the variable that holds a copy of `$wp_the_query` global query that could/can be modified by plugins and themes
- `$wp_the_query` is the variable that holds an unmodified copy of the global query object and used to reset the `$wp_query` object when we call [wp_reset_query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query)

I think you now understand as to why it makes sense to have both available to us.

Comment: that's what i was looking for. can you suggest safe way to access `wp_the_query` from plugins?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by safe... but `$GLOBALS[ 'wp_the_query' ]` should give you access to that variable.

Comment: i mean that variable is not immediately accessible from plugin. it does not work with init action hook.

Comment: Oh ok, I believe this is normal behaviour because your hook is too soon.  The query is not set up yet at `init`. Try a later hook like `wp` or `template_redirect`, you should have access to the variable.  Check out [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for reference on hook sequence.